# How to add a final field to an existing spring-data-mongodb document collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have an existing document collection using `spring-data-mongodb` version `1.0.2.RELEASE`.

```
@Document
public class Snapshot {
    @Id
    private final long id;
    private final String description;
    private final boolean active;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Snapshot(long id, String description, boolean active) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a new property `private final boolean billable;`. Since the properties are `final` they need to be set in the constructor. If I add the new property to the constructor, then the application can no longer read the existing docs.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.some.package.Snapshot]: Illegal arguments for constructor;
```

As far as I can tell, you cannot have multiple constructors declared as `@PersistenceContstructor`so unless I manually update the existing documents to contain the `billable` field, I have no way to add a `final` property to this existing collection.

Has anyone found a solution to this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to add a new `private final` field to an existing collection using only the `@PersistenceContstructor` annotation. Instead I needed to add an `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` implementation to handle the logic for me.

Here's what my converter ended up looking like:

```
@ReadingConverter
public class SnapshotReadingConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Snapshot> {

    @Override
    public Snapshot convert(DBObject source) {
        long id = (Long) source.get("_id");
        String description = (String) source.get("description");
        boolean active = (Boolean) source.get("active");
        boolean billable = false;
        if (source.get("billable") != null) {
            billable = (Boolean) source.get("billable");
        }
        return new Snapshot(id, description, active, billable);
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone else in the future.